# PUT operation creates new embedded document instead of updating it on Api Platform

Tags: mongodb, symfony4, doctrine-odm, api-platform.com

I am stuck on an issue I cannot solve for few days now. As said in the title, Api Platform PUT operation based on annotations doesn't work as expected with regards to partial update on embedded document with MongoDB ODM.

Indeed, despite all the different configurations I tried, I didn't succeed in updating an embedded document already set in a parent document.

I tried to change annotations in relevant documents, for example by changing normalization and denormalization groups, by trying different embedded document strategies, by setting specific itemOperations for PUT method, etc. Documentation is quite poor on this specific issue because it seems mainly made for SQL operations using Doctrine ORM.

The most "interesting" information I found comes from this chapter in Api Platform documentation : https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#denormalization

As it is written "If an @id key is present in the embedded resource, then the object corresponding to the given URI will be retrieved through the data provider. Any changes in the embedded relation will also be applied to that object.", corresponding document should be retrieved, but it doesn't.

I have a parent document, Page, with an embedded document, Basic, in an embedOne relationship.

```
/**
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"basic.name": "ipartial", "basic.title": "exact"})
 * 
 * @ApiResource(
 *  normalizationContext={"groups"={"read"}},
 *  denormalizationContext={"groups"={"write"}}
 * )
 *
 * @ODM\Document
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @ODM\Id(strategy="increment", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Embedded document with data shared by all Pages and Modules such as name, title, etc.
     * 
     * @Assert\Valid
     * @Groups({"read", "write"})
     * @ODM\EmbedOne(targetDocument=Basic::class, strategy="set")
     */
    private $basic;
}
```

On the other side, I have Basic embedded document :

```
/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * 
 * @ODM\EmbeddedDocument
 */
class Basic
{
    /**
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
     * @Groups({"read", "write"})
     * @ODM\Id(strategy="INCREMENT", type="integer")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @Groups({"read", "write"})
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @Groups({"read", "write"})
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Groups({"read", "write"})
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     */
    private $category;
}
```

So when I make a "POST" request on /api/pages such as this one:

```
{
    "basic": {
        "title": "Master",
        "name": "Peter Jackson",
        "category": "Director"
    }
}
```

I receive this 201 response:

```
{
    "@context": "\/api\/contexts\/Page",
    "@id": "\/api\/pages\/11",
    "@type": "Page",
    "basic": {
        "@id": "\/api\/basics\/21",
        "@type": "Basic",
        "id": 21,
        "title": "Master",
        "name": "Peter Jackson",
        "category": "Director"
    }
}
```

But I make a "PUT" request on this resource through api/pages/11 with those parameters:

```
{
  "basic": {
    "title": "Master",
    "name": "Steven Spielberg",
    "category": "Director"
  }
}
```

I receive this 200 response:

```
{
    "@context": "\/api\/contexts\/Page",
    "@id": "\/api\/pages\/11",
    "@type": "Page",
    "basic": {
        "@id": "\/api\/basics\/22",
        "@type": "Basic",
        "id": 22,
        "title": "Master",
        "name": "Steven Spielberg",
        "category": "Director"
    }
}
```

As you can see a new Basic embedded document is generated for the PUT operation in which the values set in the request are used. But I don't want this to happen, I want to systematically update the embedded document created, since it has been created. Thanks a lot if you know how to deal with this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem.
You need to set the id on embedded Relations otherwise they will be created.

```
{
  "basic": {
    "@id": "\/api\/basics\/21",
    "title": "Master",
    "name": "Steven Spielberg",
    "category": "Director"
  }
}
```

From the docs:

```
If an @id key is present in the embedded resource, then the object corresponding to the given URI will be retrieved through the data provider. Any changes in the embedded relation will also be applied to that object.

If no @id key exists, a new object will be created containing data provided in the embedded JSON document.
```

Comment: Hi !

Thanks for your answer. Actually I tried this solution and it didn't work. The reason is that "\/api\/basics\/21" cannot be requested alone, without its embedding parent. So it's throwing an error message saying I can't acceed this resource (I don't remember exactly which one).

Finally, after trying different solutions, I came to the conclusion it was better to follow the SQL logic of API Platform and avoid embedded documents. Definitely not the best solution but at least it works and I can keep it DRY with traits.

Comment: Hi @Domopus, you must enable the get item operation on "basic" entity in order to reference it with an IRI in another document